# Message destination host unreachable from default gateway

Tags: packet, loss

I have some *PCs (win) + server + network printers* all connected to the same switch and all configured in the same *subnet*.

> When the switch is not connected to the uplink everything works fine
>   (my office is isolated from the rest of the world). But when we
>   connect the uplink (to other switches) we have random packet loss.

If I ping my subnet  (my PC's!!!) I get random temporary messages "**destination host unreachable**" replied from my default gateway (???), but if I ping outside my subnet I have no packet loss. When I'm getting the "**host unreachable message**" in my ARP table I see the default gateway MAC address at the IP that I'm pinging (???).

What's going on? Thanks